# RKE Ports requirements - is communication between rke components is encrypted?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, rke

in order to deploy rke, some ports need to be opened for communication between rke nodes. for instance between worker nodes the below ports :

"22"  -  "179" - "5473" -  "8472" - "9099" - "10250" - "10251" - "10252" - "10254" - "3260" - "2049" - "111" - "9090" - "9094" - "8081"

are communication over those ports is encrypted or not ?

Thanks in advance
Regards

Answer (score 0):

By default it is not encrypted.All traffic between Rancher Server pods is done over the overlay network which can be encrypted. However, all external communication nodes, downstream clusters, etc.) with Rancher is done over SSL using the API.

Check this [link](https://forums.rancher.com/t/rancher-on-bare-metal-servers-is-it-secure-by-default/16039) for more information